# Setting relative Tex-Master file in Latex

Tags: emacs, latex, aquamacs, auctex

I use Aquamacs and TeX Live 2009 to edit my LaTeX files. As my publications tend to get quite big, I want to structure the source folder containing all my LaTeX files. Like e.g.

- [bib]
- [images]
- [chapters]

  - chapter1.tex
  - chapter2.tex
- main.tex

One can define the `%%% TeX-master: "main"` local variable at the end of each "sub" file to define a master file that contains all headers etc. That works fine if the subfiles are in the same directory as the main file. If I try to define the main file here (e.g. main.tex in chapter1.tex), LaTeX cannot find the specified file.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Aquamacs' menu bar go to `Latex / Multifile/Parsing / Reset Buffer` or Shortcut `^C ^N`.
When specifying `%%% TeX-master: "../main"` in one of the chapters in the subfolders, the main tex file is correctly compiled!

Comment: You just solved a problem that I was dealing with for several weeks. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea (not tested):

```
%%% TeX-master: "../main"
```

`..` is the usual Unix shortcut for *one directory level above*. I don't know if this works for the TeX-master variable of AUCTeX, but it is worth a try.

Comment: In fact, it is ;) The problem was, that you have to reset your buffer in order to get Aquamacs to recognize, that the variable has changed (see following post). Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

The main latex file which contains all the headers and gets compile can include all the chapter files via:

```
[...]
\input{chapters/chapter1.tex}
\input{chapters/chapter2.tex}
\input{chapters/chapterTitleOfChapter.tex}
[...]
```

You do not need to have each chapter include the main file.  Or am I missing something you are doing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, it is usual to include all the chapter like this. The reason why I want to define the TeX-Master variable is, that I don't have to jump back to the Main-buffer every time I want to compile my file.

If the subpage is in the same directory, I click compile (in the chapter buffer) and aquamacs compiles the main-file for me. It doesn't, when the subpage is in a subdirectory...